# Adding Accept multipart/related;type=application/octet-stream to HttpRequestMessage throws error

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclient

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://someurl"));
request.Headers.Add("Accept","multipart/related;type=application/octet-stream");
```

above code throws below exception

System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=The format of value 'multipart/related;type=application/octet-stream' is invalid.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)
   at deleteit.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\310227436\source\repos\deleteit\deleteit\Program.cs:line 14

My requirement is I must have to "multipart/related;type=application/octet-stream" as Accept header, as service needs that.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient` mostly uses strongly typed headers or tries to validate the input.

Try using:

```
request.Headers
.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept","multipart/related;type=application/octet-stream");`
```